# How to setup Podbean api with Snowflake and store json data?

Tags: javascript, json, api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, podcast

I have a difficulty creating connection from Podbean api to Snowflake.
i have fetched the data using Curl in Podbean API but there is no analytics and stuff in Podbean ,so need to create a connection between podbean and snowflake for further analytics.

Comment: What is it that you want to do, what have you tried, and what results did you get? [Edit] the question to give us the information we need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the connection done using the External OAuth wherein using the client_credentials flow or the auth_code flow, the connection to Snowflake can be achieved.

Details on External Oauth for SF are here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-ext-overview.html

Details for PodBean API authentication are here: https://developers.podbean.com/podbean-api-docs/#api-Authentication-Login_Dialog